# Get rid of Gutter in TwitterBootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Maybe I'm crazy but is there not a way to get rid of the 20px gutter on the twitter bootstrap?  For example I've used frameworks that use an alpha and omega that over-ride the gutter to give it a margin:0px; I'm not currently seeing anything like this in the twitter bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 9):

With the bootstrap you don't need a class to remove the gutter, it is removed by the `.row` class where you place your `span` divs automatically so everything sits nicely within the grid.

```
.row {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

A little clarification.

The other frameworks, such as the 960.gs grid, use an `.alpha` and `.omega` to remove the excess margin on the left or right of a grid so they can sit the grid elements nicely within a line. With the bootstrap this is not the case anymore since the grid has that excess margin removed by the `.row` div, which is required to have your `.span` divs sit nicely within the grid.

Comment: That option doesn't fix the omega gutter.

Comment: <div class="span6 row">
       <p>content goes here</p>
    </div><!--/.span6 -->

this still gives my .span6 a margin-left: 30px; because of the [class*="span"] in bootstrap-responsive.css: line:450 -> it over-rides it.

Comment: @b-lew the markup goes like this: `<div class="row"> <div class="span6 "><p>content goes here</p></div></div><!--/.span6 -->`

Comment: @Karl the way the bootstrap grid is set, the `.row div is exactly made to remove the omega margin. The alpha margin is irrelevant with the bootstrap.

Comment: @AndresIlich I did that as well. It does get rid of the margin on the outside but I still have a margin-left: 30px; on my .span6 -> is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: @b-lew can you post your markup? try including it in  http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can take a look

Comment: Clever. Makes sense to omit the omega gutter anyway. I retract my comment. Good idea.

Comment: @AndresIlich http://4site.delineamultimedia.com/index.php -> you can see what i'm trying to do here. you can see that my background image on the carousel is getting cut off a couple of pixels on the left (not a lot but enough to be annoying). I'd like to get rid of that margin so that its not getting cut off anymore.

Comment: Yea I usually use another framework but I thought I'd give this a try since its so popular. I'll just use the one I'm use too until thats fixed.

Comment: @b-lew i don't see it, your carousel is very small. Is it supposed to encompass the whole container?

Comment: @b-lew try this, removed an extra `.row` div you had in place, http://jsfiddle.net/ELfBV/1/show/ .. edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ELfBV/1/)

Comment: I really only see one .row in there. the markup looks okay to me. I really can't believe the twitter bootstrap doesn't have something like that built into it. haha surprises me.

Comment: @b-lew i'm still not able to see where your extra margin is coming from, can you illustrate it on a screenshot? Everything looks the same to me (in FF/Chrome/IE).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

Don't see anything in the documentation either, but here is a fix:

If you want to remove the gutter on the left and right ends of your container, you will have to add a class for the .alpha and the .omega.

```
.alpha { margin-left: 0; }
.omega { margin-right: 0; }
```

If you want to change all the gutters:

In the variables.less file, you can change the Gutter width:

```
// GRID
// --------------------------------------------------

// Default 940px grid
// -------------------------

@gridGutterWidth: 20px;
```

Comment: But that changes all of the gutter width's... I'm not wanting that. I thought maybe a feature like this was built into the framework. I'll just add my own css to make it work.

Comment: I updated my answer, I don't see anything in the documentation that allows the removal of the of the alpha and omega gutters. But you can easily add classes to your CSS to fix it.

Comment: Yea I'll just add that css... weird I would think as popular as that framework is they'd already have that in there. Thanks for clarifying that I'm not nuts though. I appreciate your time!

Comment: I agree. Not a problem! Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 3):

Just download a custom version of the framework from here

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables

and make the gridGutter = 0px

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, this solved it for my pretty nice:

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic...but I'm sure it's still an issue for folks. I found this very useful CSS that solved it for me. Enjoy!

```
/* remove spacing between middle columns */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
/* remove right padding from first column */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child {
  padding-right:0;
}
/* remove left padding from first column */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:last-child {
  padding-left:0;
}

/* only for column content visible */
.col-lg-1>div {background-color:#ddd;}
```

[CSS Source - http://bootply.com/109530](http://www.bootply.com/109530)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your content into container-fluid div:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
...
</div>
```

And then modify (in bootstrap.css) or override the container-fluid class:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
```

boostrap-responsive.css has the same class so you can set different margins for mobile screens vs. desktop screens.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add a custom style similar to alpha and omega in 960.gs framework.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin-right: -15px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your custom css:

```
.row-nogutter {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
 }
```

And using your row like `<div class='row row-nogutter'>`

If this still doesn't work try adding `!important` but I don't recommend it.