# Set column width of table in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a c# project using Razor and bootstrap in which there is a table in a page, with several columns.

Now, Bootstrap automatically sets the width of each column to occupy an equal amount of space inside the table, however this is not ideal.

In my table, some columns have more information and need to be wider than others.

This does not happen, and as a result, I end up with a table that has 2 images, one on top of the other (when they should be in the same line), looking horrible.

My approach to fix this problem was the following:

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Item Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(Item anItemin Model.ItemsList){
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @anItem.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <img class="span6" src="single_chevron/green.png" />
                            <img class="span6" src="single_chevron/white.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now, clearly this fix is not working. I have also tried the classes `inline`, `form-inline`, `container`, and `input-append` to force the images to stay on the same line (and not one on top of the other) but nothing works.

So basically, I am searching for one of two ways to attack the problem:

- Force the images to stay on the same line
- Make the second column bigger in bootstrap so the images have enough space

Is there a clean way to achieve any of these objectives?

Comment: can you put it a jsfiddle to allow others to quickly change your code?

Comment: Instead of placing `span6` in the `img`, have you tried to use 2 `div` (one for each image)? You can either still use the `img` tag inside each `div` or set those images as the `div`s backgrounds (you must set a specific height for the `div`s)... These methods may solve a lot of other troubles as well (at least they did for me). If they do, answer your own question :)

Comment: @blairmeister : since neither stackoverflow nor jsfiddle support Bootstrap 2.3.2 as a library (only Angular) I am afraid that doing so is not possible unless I manually import the entire bootstrap 2.3.2 library myself :S

Comment: @Armfoot: setting another div for the second image will for sure make it go under the first one as divs work like paragraphs. As for setting the image as background, it won't work because of the first reason. The way I see it, I can only use 1 div to solve this.

Comment: It will go under because of the `span12` with 2 `span6` inside. The `span6` still has the gutter width and its dimensions are calculated according to the parent `row-fluid`. You can either [get rid of the gutter width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318546/get-rid-of-gutter-in-twitterbootstrap) (with `alpha` and `omega`), or you try one of the [solutions in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30619051/1326147). It's preferable not to use the `alpha` and `omega` classes... (if you need to update to the new version, you have to adjust a lot more code if you're using them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap classes in the old version needed some considerations:

- a `row` should have `span` as children;
- a `span` may have `row` as children but should not have other `span` as direct children to preserve the grid;
- `img` tags are not very friendly with `span` classes, therefore try avoiding them.

These are possible solutions:

### A

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="single_chevron/green.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="single_chevron/white.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### B

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <img src="single_chevron/green.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <img src="single_chevron/white.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### C

```
<style>
.common-chevron {height: 100px}
#single-chevron-green {background-image: url(single_chevron/green.png)}
#single-chevron-white {background-image: url(single_chevron/white.png)}
</style>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="single-chevron-green" class="span6 common-chevron">
    </div>
    <div id="single-chevron-white" class="span6 common-chevron">
    </div>
</div>
```

For this one, you may need more CSS rules like `background-position` to get them right.